# 'Export to zip file' in Android Studio leads to 1.2gb + archive size

Tags: ios, flutter

First of all, I am a complete beginner. I am always using 'export to zip file' to save my flutter code (I am not familiarized with Github right now ;-) ). The overall filesize of the zip is now around 1.2 gigabyte - Android folder: 60mb, iOS folder: 1.1gb.

It is a simple chat app without much graphics etc.

Is it normal? Don't want that the final app size is that large. Any idea how to save my code without that much overload?

Best, 
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's normal - you have a whole bunch of intermediate build artifacts under your source folder.

The purpose of those `.gitignore` files that you find in your source tree is to tell git which files are the temporary build files or other configuration files specific to your machine. Git uses then to decide which files should be saved for posterity in source control, and which ones it should ignore.

If you are not going to use git, use the gitignore files to see which folders you can manually exclude from your zip file. (The `build` folder will probably be the main culprit.)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you use git. You can use dropbox or google drive folders for your project, this way they can auto sync your files. Try to compress your project folder from your operating system's file manager and compare the sizes. I don't think 1.1gb ios folder is normal.

Answer (score 0):

**Usually this must not happen (until u have used large media files).**

One reason of file size increase is,
"apk / aab" files in "app\release" folder are not deleted while project is build,
like they are deleted in "app\build\outputs\apk\debug" folder.

You can delete previous signed apk from "app\release",
(if you have published them).
As these "apk / aab" are safely stored on google developer account.

**Also don't forget to export your ".zip"**
out of the project folder other wise it be like "zip in zip and zip in zip and so on ..."